# Assets 2 loses Rackspace thumbnails

Tags: assets

The first time I upload via Rackspace, the thumbnails on the backend appear fine.

However, if I delete the expressionengine/cache directory and it regenerates the images, the result is 70 byte 'jpgs' are created in expressionengine/cache/assets/rs_sources with the following content

`<html><h1>Not Found</h1><p>The resource could not be found.`

- i.e. the response you would get from Rackspace if the image cannot be found.

However, the images are available and accessible (right click -> View file returns the correct image with a Rackspace URL). They also appear fine on the front-end, so it's just the process which deals with the generation of thumbnails for the backend.

Answer (score 1):

I found that when you use the subfolder option, the leading forward slash is removed which malforms the URL which means the curl request fails

In sources.rs.php, I added a forward slash manually to compensate on line 1089, but there is obviously a deeper issue as to why the forward slash gets stripped - just don't have time right now to figure it out.

`$prefix = isset($this->settings()->subfolder) ? $this->settings()->subfolder . "/" : '';`

Comment: Richard, that's a nice catch. It was fixed two days ago internally and will be included in the next Assets release, that will be coming out next week.

Sorry you had to run into this issue like that :(